# AngularJS and ns-select without ng-option

Tags: angularjs, select

in my page I load the content of a div via "ng-include src". In this content I have a <select> item:

```
<select name="relationship" ng-model="userEdit.relationship">
                <?php
                $tree = taxonomy_get_tree(5);
                foreach ($tree as $row) {
                    echo "<option value=".$row->tid.">".$row->name."</option>\n";
                }
                ?>
</select>
```

In my "controller" function I can not to create this tree into an array to pass to "ng-options" because I have no access to source tree via web. I can only read the full HTML form. I can change the source of the form (if I need to inject something for example) but I can not get the original tree in my controller.

However, the HTML is ok, but when I choose my "relationship" and send the form (ng-click="myfunction()") to my controller function i can see that there is no "relationship" in "userEdit" object.

Where is my error ?

Thanks.

Comment: Strange. All seems correct… Can you show the resulting HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes

```
echo "<option value='".$row->tid."'>".$row->name."</option>\n";
```